# Editing data in Modal in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with editing data in the bootstrap modal.

The problem is that in the modal, only first record from the database is displayed.

Modal only displays the problem because it retrieves data from 1 record.

My code AngularJS:

```
    $scope.editLink = function( link ){

      var linkdId = $routeParams.id;
       $scope.id =  linkdId;

      $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'api/admin/links/get/' + linkdId
       }).then(function (response){
          $scope.edlink = response.data.records;

       },function (error){
          console.log('Blad we wczytywaniu danych');
       });

   }
```

View.html

Edit

```
      <div class="modal fade" id="edit-data" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="POST" name="editLinked" role="form" ng-submit="saveChanges( link )">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Item</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="edlink.login">
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="edlink.password">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="edlink.links">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="editLinked.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary create-crud">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share your code related to edit function . you should filter data accordingly to show on model.  simply declare a function `editRecord` with parameter taking index and based on the index filter from $scope.link & store it in say $scope.editData & bind to model popup on edit button click .

Comment: @supercool I changed my code, but nothing helped.

Comment: U can put up a plunker it show your issue . From what I see from the code above there are few issues like in function link parameter is no where used etc . Can u update your complete HTML code with foreach loop .